# Raw Audio Conversion

Tags: multimedia, gstreamer

While, I'm reading gstreamer document I found this: "
Audioconvert converts raw audio buffers between various possible formats.
It supports integer to float conversion, width/depth conversion, signedness and endianness conversion and channel transformations."
I only understand

- "depth" (bit number per sample)
- "signedness and endianness" (for data representation)

And now, I'm looking for explanations of :

- "integer to float conversion"
- "width"
- "channel transformations"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
* "integer to float conversion"
```

each audio sample in a stream contains a number that represents the 'height' of the wave at that point - this number is either an integer (e.g 45) or a floating point number (e.g 0.345).
different streams use different conventions - a single gstreamer pipeline is likely to contain lots of different streams; some using integer representation, others using float. audioconvert automatically converts between these so you don't have to worry about it.

```
* "width"
```

width is the number of bits *allocated* to an audio sample - as opposed to the depth, which is the number of bits actually used. width > depth. e.g 24bit sound has a depth of 24 and a width of 32. think of it as extra padding.

```
* "channel transformations"
```

mono to stereo conversion and vice versa